# Emacs or Spacemacs

Tags: copy-paste

Trying to understand who to copy/paste between Spacemacs or Emacs and terminal and browser. Using Spacemacs with Ubuntu 16.04 presently
Tried configuring xcopy and confused about it.  Can’t seem to yank and paste or copy and paste or middle click and paste or any other combo between browser and Spacemacs

Comment: I got tired of chasing my tail with Spacemacs uninstalled it and loaded Emacs-Evil-Mode and copy/paste with mouse works just fine.  Hurray!!!

Comment: The subject line is virtually meaningless.  Please edit it so that it indicates in some way the nature of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got tired of chasing my tail with Spacemacs uninstalled it, and loaded Emacs-Evil-Mode and copy/paste with mouse works just fine.  Hurray!!!

Comment: Please elaborate and clarify (e.g. "with Spacemace uninstalled i"?). Consider providing a link or other reference for "Emacs-Evil-Mode".